# Filling and accessing a global Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a global array (I know it is not recommended) that I would populate dynamically with data from an AJAX request. It looks like this:

```
var myArray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var min = "someUrl.js";

  function somenewFunc(json) {
    alert(json);
  }

  (function someFunc() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: min + '?callback=jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'somenewFunc',
      jsonp: 'callback',
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
        myArray = [];

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
          myArray.push(item.id);
        });
      },
      complete: function() {
        setTimeout(someFunc, 15000);
      }
    });
  })();
});

console.log(myArray);
```

I am deleting the array's content at the beginning of the success method as I don't want to it hold the same data multiple times. I could display the array's content inside the AJAX request but not outside. The console output shows me an empty array.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ajax call is asynchronous, so `console.log(myArray)` runs before the data is returned.

Comment: Let-alone it's not recommended... unless you create a *parent* IIFE scope.

Comment: You only examine the value of the array when the JS first loads, before the ready event even fires.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies! I didn't know such a thread existed already. I'll take a look at it.